# Dynamically created multi select box values not inserted correctly

Tags: php, mysql

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[]" required="required">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">AAA</option>
            <option value="2">BBB</option>
            <option value="3">CCC</option>
            <option value="4">DDD</option>
            <option value="5">EEE</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[]" id="service" multiple="multiple">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">List 1</option>
            <option value="2">List 2</option>
            <option value="3">List 3</option>
            <option value="4">List 4</option>
            <option value="5">List 5</option>
            <option value="6">List 6</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[]" required="required">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">AAA</option>
            <option value="2">BBB</option>
            <option value="3">CCC</option>
            <option value="4">DDD</option>
            <option value="5">EEE</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[]" id="service" multiple="multiple">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">List 1</option>
            <option value="2">List 2</option>
            <option value="3">List 3</option>
            <option value="4">List 4</option>
            <option value="5">List 5</option>
            <option value="6">List 6</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[]" required="required">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">AAA</option>
            <option value="2">BBB</option>
            <option value="3">CCC</option>
            <option value="4">DDD</option>
            <option value="5">EEE</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[]" id="service" multiple="multiple">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">List 1</option>
            <option value="2">List 2</option>
            <option value="3">List 3</option>
            <option value="4">List 4</option>
            <option value="5">List 5</option>
            <option value="6">List 6</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This table rows are generated dynamicaly, its input field values are passed as an array and one of the select box is multiselect

**Here is my php code**

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
foreach ($reson as $id => $value) {
    $resona = ($reson[$id]);
    $namep = ($name[$id]);
    $rsid = $ob->insert_data('tbl_reson',array("reson" => $resona, "name" => $namep), true);
    foreach ($service as $ii => $valu) {
        $r_service = ($service[$ii]);
        $ob->insert_data('tbl_service',array("reson_id" => $rsid, "service" => $r_service));
    }
}
?>
```

Suppose here we have 3 rows and I select two multiple option from first row and three options from second row and four options from third row.

And when inserted into the DB, the selected options become same for all rows (All the options selected in multiselect are grouped into one array and saved into each field).

- First table

  ```
  ------------------------------
      id  |   resn    |   name
  ------------------------------
      1   |   1       |   Test
      2   |   2       |   aaa
      3   |   3       |   bbb
  ------------------------------
  ```
- Second Table

  ```
  --------------------------------    
      id  |   resnid  |   service
  --------------------------------
      1   |   1       |       1
      2   |   1       |       2
      3   |   2       |       3
      4   |   2       |       4
      5   |   2       |       5
      6   |   3       |       6
  ```
- Second Table Current list

  ```
  -------------------------------- 
      id  |   resnid  |   service
  --------------------------------
      1   |   1       |       1
      2   |   1       |       2
      3   |   1       |       3
      4   |   1       |       4
      5   |   1       |       5
      6   |   1       |       6
      7   |   2       |       1
      8   |   2       |       2
      9   |   2       |       3
      10  |   2       |       4
      11  |   2       |       5
      12  |   2       |       6
  ```
- etc...

But what I need is to insert `reson[]` and `name[]` in one table and service in another table based on last inserted id of the first table

Please Help to achieve this.

Comment: not sure about mysql, but I would approach this in MSSQL using staging tables and the output method/clause.

Comment: please see table structure

Comment: Try and use readable column names. It's very important in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly set the key for each field. The key for `reson` and `name` should match the key for `service`. Here is an example for the names to use.

```
reson[0]
name[0]
service[0][]

reson[1]
name[1]
service[1][]

reson[2]
name[2]
service[2][]
```

The `service` field has an additional `[]` because it sends multiple values for each row.

Since you said that you are creating the rows dynamically, you could easily use a loop counter to create these names. Like this:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) { ?>

    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[<?php echo $i; ?>]" required="required">
        ...
    </select>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[<?php echo $i; ?>][]" id="service" multiple="multiple">
        ...
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>]" placeholder="Name" />

<?php } ?>
```

And then your PHP code would have to be like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($reson as $id => $value) {
    $reson = ($reson[$id]);
    $namep = ($name[$id]);
    $rsid = $ob->insert_data('tbl_reson',array("reson" => $reson, "name" => $namep), true);
    foreach ($service[$id] as $ii => $valu) {
        $r_service = $val;
        $ob->insert_data('tbl_service',array("reson_id" => $rsid, "service" => $r_service));
    }
}
?>
```

### Response to your comment below

You said that you are using the following Javascript code to create new rows:

```
var i=$('.div').length+1; $('#lobrows').append('
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple="multiple" name="service['+i+'][]" id="service'+i+'">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <?php for($k=0; $k<=10;$k++){?><option value="Reason <?php echo $k;?>">Reason <?php echo $k;?></option>
    <?php }?></select>
');
```

You should make sure that you are also adding the `name` and `reson` in the same row. They should all use the same `i` value for their names. Like this:

```
var i=$('.div').length+1; $('#lobrows').append('
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson['+i+']" required="required">
    </select>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple="multiple" name="service['+i+'][]" id="service'+i+'">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <?php for($k=0; $k<=10;$k++){?><option value="Reason <?php echo $k;?>">Reason <?php echo $k;?></option>
    <?php }?></select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name['+i+']" placeholder="Name" />
');
```

Comment: It Shows This error, 
Notice: Array to string conversion in--------------- on line 69.
 $r_service is an array.

Comment: I add 3 row and remove 2nd row then submit form, i got Notice: Undefined offset: 1. and Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Sambhu Sorry, please see my edits. `$r_service` should be assigned to `$val` in the loop. Also, if you use a loop to create the rows, you can use a loop counter to create the names.

Comment: this rows are created by jquery when click add button. `var i=$('.div').length+1; $('#lobrows').append('<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple="multiple" name="service['+i+'][]" id="service'+i+'"><option>--Select--</option><?php for($k=0; $k<=10;$k++){?><option value="Reason <?php echo $k;?>">Reason <?php echo $k;?></option><?php }?></select>');`, Suppose I add 3 row and remove 2nd row then submit form, i got Notice: Undefined offset: 1. and Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Sambhu You should be adding the `reson` and `name` fields in the `append` too. They should all use the same `i` value for the name.

Comment: @Sambhu I updated my answer. Look at the bottom part.

Comment: Thanks @Kodos Johnson

Answer (score 0):

i think you have problem in foreach in foreach so after one record is inserted in first table other foreach is insert all record in second table with only first reson_id please try following code.

```
<?php
 extract($_POST);
 foreach ($reson as $id => $value) {
 $resona = ($reson[$id]);
 $namep = ($name[$id]);
 $rsid = $ob->insert_data('tbl_reson',array("reson" => $resona, "name" => $namep), true);
 $r_service = ($service[$id]);
 $ob->insert_data('tbl_service',array("reson_id" => $rsid, "service" => $r_service));
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do the first `INSERT`
2. Perform `$id = ... SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`;  (by whatever "ob" does.)
3. Use `$id` in the second `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
extract($_POST);
   $rsid = array();
    foreach ($reson as $id => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $key => $val)
            {
                $resona = ($val);
                $namep = ($name[$id]);
                $rsid[] = $ob->insert_data('tbl_reson',array("reson" => $resona, "name" => $namep), true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $resona = ($value);
            $namep = ($name[$id]);
            $rsid[] = $ob->insert_data('tbl_reson',array("reson" => $resona, "name" => $namep), true);
        }
    }
    foreach ($service as $ii => $valu) {
        if(is_array($valu)){
            foreach($valu as $key => $val)
            {
                $r_service = ($val);
                foreach($rsid as $reson_id)
                    $ob->insert_data('tbl_service',array("reson_id" => $reson_id, "service" => $r_service));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $r_service = ($valu);
            foreach($rsid as $reson_id)
                $ob->insert_data('tbl_service',array("reson_id" => $reson_id, "service" => $r_service));
        }


    }
```